# Sonar Scanner engine is not started

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube

I follow the instruction at [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Ant](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) to analyzing an ant project and got following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Projects\my-sonar\build.xml
     [echo] Build properties read from build.properties
clean:
sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.5
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/Projects/my-sonar/.ant/lib/sonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\test\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load global settings

BUILD FAILED
C:\Projects\my-sonar\build.xml:541: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner engine is not started. Unable to execute task.
```

I'm using JDK 1.8 and connecting to a remote SonarQube server.

Do I have to start sonar-scanner as a service locally?

Any helps are appreciated.

UPDATE:

This works after adding "sonar.login" & "sonar.password" in build.xml. The error message is kind of misleading...

Comment: SonarQube server version is 6.4

Comment: I had same issue on production environment. Resolved it by adding the 2 properties you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I received the exact same log message from the production environment. The configuration works in the test environment. The issue was credentials. I agree with your update, "The error message is kind of misleading..."

In my case the SonarQube token was incorrect in the sonar-project.properties file. I corrected the token and reran the analysis successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding "sonar.login" & "sonar.password", it would be better to generate a token and just add sonar.login property.
Password is not required if an authentication token is being used.
[This](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) is how a token can be generated.