# /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis/build.xml:63: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch is not started. Unable to execute task

Tags: jenkins, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to integrate Sonar task in Ant build using Jenkins. SonarQube server is running successfully at the default port . SonarQube web interface is successfully opening.

Problem is when I am running Sonar task from Ant build file using Jenkins it is giving error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch is not started. Unable to execute task

The sonar task ANt build Jenkins Console output is defined as below:

```
   Console Output

Started by user Pradeep Podishetty
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done

Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis/build.xml

deletesrc:

-check-package-xml:

-create-default-package-xml:

download:
 [codescan] Manifest file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis/petra/src/package.xml
 [codescan] Retrieving results with API Version 40.0...
 [codescan] ...in progress (waiting for 2000ms)
 [codescan] ...in progress (waiting for 4000ms)
 [codescan] ...in progress (waiting for 8000ms)
 [codescan] ...in progress (waiting for 16000ms)
 [codescan] Retrieve warnings:
 [codescan] unpackaged/package.xml - Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:AppMenu and file name:AppSwitcher.
 [codescan] 
 [codescan] Writing files to disk

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 18 seconds
[salesforce-code-analysis] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/default/bin/ant -Dsonar.projectKey=Test -Dsonar.projectName=GIT-Test-Dev -Dsalesforce.url=https://test.salesforce.com/ -Dsalesforce.username=*************** -Dsonar.host.url=https://static.itx-tools.net -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ******** -Duser.dir=petra sonar
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis/build.xml

sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.1 compiled on February 2 2017
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.5
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar
[sonar:sonar] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[sonar:sonar] Load global repositories

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/salesforce-code-analysis/build.xml:63: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch is not started. Unable to execute task.
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.checkStarted(Batch.java:139)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doStop(Batch.java:175)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.stop(Batch.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.stop(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStop(EmbeddedScanner.java:226)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.stop(EmbeddedScanner.java:165)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.launchAnalysis(SonarQubeTask.java:101)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.execute(SonarQubeTask.java:81)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)

Total time: 2 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My Build.xml looks like this:

```
<project name="VillageChief DataHub" xmlns:sf="salesforce">
  <!-- Pick up per-project folder settings-->
  <property file="${user.dir}/sonar-project.properties"/>

  <!-- put global settings in here -->
  <property file="${basedir}/antbuild.properties"/> 

  <!-- proxy settings -->
  <property name="http.proxyHost" value="" />
  <property name="http.proxyPort" value="0" />
  <property name="http.proxyUser" value="" />
  <property name="http.proxyPassword" value="" />
  <property name="http.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost|*.local|127.*|[::1]" />

  <!--if ntlm is used -->
  <!--<property name="http.auth.ntlm.domain" value="" />-->

  <!-- tell ant about proxy -->
  <setproxy proxyhost="${http.proxyHost}" proxyport="${http.proxyPort}" 
            proxyuser="${http.proxyUser}" proxypassword="${http.proxyPassword}" 
            nonproxyhosts="${http.nonProxyHosts}"/>

  <!-- some tasks in codescan need https equivalents -->
  <property name="https.proxyHost" value="${http.proxyHost}" />
  <property name="https.proxyPort" value="${http.proxyPort}" />
  <property name="https.proxyUser" value="${http.proxyUser}" />
  <property name="https.proxyPassword" value="${http.proxyPassword}" />

  <!-- define if not already defined properties -->
  <property name="salesforce.url" value="https://www.salesforce.com" />

  <!-- Define the ant tasks. Use ant.file.dir to ensure we look for the jar files next to antbuild.xml -->
  <dirname file="${ant.file}" property="ant.file.dir" />
  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${ant.file.dir}/../sonarqube-ant-task-2.5.jar" />
  </taskdef>
  <taskdef name='codescan' classname='com.villagechief.codescan.versions.ant.ScmCommitterTask'>
    <classpath path="${ant.file.dir}/../force-versions-1.4.jar" />
  </taskdef>

  <!-- Add the target -->
  <target name="sonar">
    <!-- Please see https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters for details on parameters to pass to SonarQube -->

    <!-- location properties -->
    <property name="sonar.projectBaseDir" value="${user.dir}" />

    <!-- define if not already defined properties -->
    <property name="salesforce.url" value="https://www.salesforce.com" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    <property name="sonar.sources" value="${user.dir}/src" />
    <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="utf8" />
    <property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000" />

    <!-- If the Anyone group is not granted Execute Analysis permission or if the SonarQube instance 
         is secured (the sonar.forceAuthentication property is setto true), the credentials of a us er 
         having been granted Execute Analysis permission have to be provided through the sonar.login 
         and sonar.password properties
    -->
    <!-- <property name="sonar.login" value="USER" /> -->
    <!-- <property name="sonar.password" value="PASS" /> -->

    <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" />
  </target>


  <target name="deletesrc">
    <delete dir="${user.dir}/src">
        <include name="**/*"/>
        <exclude name="package.xml"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <target name="commit">
    <codescan username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" writeFiles="true" repository="${scm}" packageXmlPath="${user.dir}/src/package.xml" outputPath="${user.dir}/src">
    <fileset dir="${user.dir}/src">
        <include name="**/*"/>
    </fileset>
    </codescan>
  </target>

  <target name="-check-package-xml">
    <available property="package.xml.exists" file="${user.dir}/src/package.xml"></available>
  </target>
  <target name="-create-default-package-xml" depends="-check-package-xml" unless="package.xml.exists">
    <copy file="${ant.file.dir}/default.package.xml" tofile="${user.dir}/src/package.xml" />
  </target>
  <target name="download" depends="-create-default-package-xml">
    <codescan username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" writeFiles="true" packageXmlPath="${user.dir}/src/package.xml" outputPath="${user.dir}/src">
      <fileset dir="${user.dir}/src">
          <include name="**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </codescan>
  </target>

  <target name="downloadAndCommit" depends="-create-default-package-xml">
    <codescan username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" writeFiles="true" repository="${scm}" packageXmlPath="${user.dir}/src/package.xml" outputPath="${user.dir}/src">
      <fileset dir="${user.dir}/src">
          <include name="**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </codescan>
  </target>

  <target name="deploy">
    <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
    <sf:deploy username="${salesforce.username}" password="${salesforce.password}" serverurl="${salesforce.url}" 
      deployroot="src"/>
  </target>

  <target name="commitall">
    <exec executable="git" dir="${user.dir}">
      <arg value="add"/>
      <arg value="-A"/>
    </exec>
    <exec executable="git" dir="${user.dir}">
      <arg value="commit"/>
      <arg value="-a"/>
      <arg value="-m"/>
      <arg value="&lt;automcommit: all&gt;"/>
    </exec>
  </target>


  <!-- <target name="analyse" depends="deletesrc, download, commit, commitall, sonar" /> -->
  <target name="analyse" depends="deletesrc, download, sonar" />
  <target name="analyze" depends="deletesrc, download, sonar" />
</project>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your analysis configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should have a problem in your configuration that make the call to the global repositories WS fail (you can enable verbose output to get more details, using property `sonar.verbose=true`).

The stacktrace is not very helpful because of a bug:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/ANTTASK-56

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding 'sonar.login' & 'sonar.password' properties in build.xml.

Refer [sonar-scanner-engine-is-not-started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039524/sonar-scanner-engine-is-not-started)